# Transfer data from access table into mysql table

Tags: mysql, data-transfer

I'm trying to transfer data from my access table into mysql table using c#, but since I have big data I can't transfer all of that data at once using this query

```
select * from record
```

so instead I used this query to transfer the data

```
DataTable ds = tempaccesscon.exexutesql("select top 100 * from  record  where time between #7/1/2013# and #7/31/2013#")
```

but the problem this query doesn't return all of the dates between #7/1/2013# and #7/31/2013#

please help me to transfer all of the data without repeating rows and missing any row

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your date field is a dateTime type

Try this

```
DataTable ds = tempaccesscon.exexutesql("select top 100 * from  record  where time between          #7/1/2013 00:00:00# and #7/31/2013 23:59:59#")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ..this didn't work ..it gives rows with date 7/1/2013 and 3 rows with date 7/6/2013 ignoring the other dates

Comment: please show me your access table structure and some sample data

Comment: Field Name : Time , Data Type : Date/Time

Comment: time values : 
1/1/2013 12:03:41 AM

Comment: I have another column Field Name : SN ..Data Type : int

Comment: post full table structure with some sample data

Comment: I have two columns in my table one is TIME which is DATE/TIME and the other one is SN which is Integer ...I couldn't upload an image of the data structure ...

Comment: example of SN value is : 321123 and of TIME value is : 1/1/2013 12:32:35 AM